# how to quote sas Macro name in If statement

Tags: sas

i am trying to write a simple macro statement. Essentially, I want to tell the program, if MIC ^= the macroname (German) then delete. But sas treat my code as if MIC ^= '&mfile'  then delete. 
Can anyone teach me how to refer to the macro name in this case please.

```
%macro match(mfile);
data TEMP; set abc; if MIC ^='&mfile' then delete; run;
%mend match;
%match(German);
```

Comment: use double quotation instead of single for "&mfile"

Comment: Thanks a lot. Problem solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Macro variable references that are enclosed in single quotation marks are not resolved, you need to use double quotation.

See [Sas documentation](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/mcrolref/61885/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a001071889.htm)  for more info